# Getting thread 1 signal SIGQUIT

Tags: objective-c

I am getting thread 1: signal SIGQUIT when running my app. But when I click on continue execution, app is resuming and completing the task. Not sure why I am getting this

```
NSArray *keyNamesForKAV = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aKAV",@"bKAV",@"cKAV",@"dKAV",@"eKAV",@"fKAV",@"gKAV",@"hKAV",@"iKAV",@"jKAV",@"kKAV",@"lKAV",@"mKAV",@"nKAV",@"oKAV",@"pKAV",@"qKAV",@"rKAV",@"sKAV",@"tKAV",@"uKAV",@"vKAV",@"wKAV",@"xKAV",@"yKAV",@"zKAV", nil];


NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
KAVTrie *kavTree = [defaults rm_customObjectForKey:@"zKAV"];
NSMutableArray *KAVArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
if (!kavTree){
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 26; i++){
        KAVTrie *trie = [[KAVTrie alloc]init];
        KAVTrie *trieLoad = [[KAVTrie alloc]init];
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[[keyNamesForKAV objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:0]]  ofType:@"plist"];
        NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSArray *array = [tempDict allKeys];

        trie = [trieLoad storeTrieInArray:array];
        [KAVArray addObject:trie];
    }
    NSLog(@"KAV objects created");

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 26; i++){
        [defaults rm_setCustomObject:[KAVArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[keyNamesForKAV objectAtIndex:i]];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }

    NSLog(@"KAV objects loaded in user defaults");

}
```

I am getting error in the second for loop

Comment: Because you did something wrong.  Want more detail?  Provide more.

Comment: I am trying to load custom objects in userdefaults. I can provide the code if needed

Comment: Is there any textfield on screen being displayed which requires keyboard Control. If yes, try clearing all the applications which uses keyboard and reload Xcode and build again. if no, please provide code if you can.

Comment: this is my code to load in userDefaults

Comment: Don't call `[defaults synchronize]` 26 times. What does `rm_setCustomObject` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. There is an issue with my KAV class file